# Showing a media player, when a playlist is clicked

Tags: jquery

I'm currently trying to have my player only show at the bottom of the screen when an item in the playlist is clicked. I wrote this code:

```
$(document).on("click", function(e){
if($(e.target).is(".playlistItem")){
  $(".playerHolder").show();
}else{
    $(".playerHolder").hide();
}
```

});

I currently have the playerHolder set to display:none. But I want it to switch to display: flex on click of the playlistItem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could toggle a display/hide class or have two separate classes. You could also add inline styles, but I believe switching classes is 'better'.

css

```
.playerHolder-hidden {
    display: none;
}
.playerHolder-show {
    display: flex;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).on("click", function(e){
if($(e.target).is(".playlistItem")){
    $(".playerHolder").addClass("playerHolder-show").removeClass("playerHolder-hidden");
}else{
    $(".playerHolder").addClass("playerHolder-hidden").removeClass("playerHolder-show");
}
```

**Edit:**
Updated jquery from comment

```
$(document).on("click", function(e){
if($(e.target).is(".playlistItem")){
    $(".playerHolder").addClass("playerHolder-show").removeClass("playerHolder-hidden");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response! it works but the player disappears if you click anywhere else on the page.

Comment: Oh, then you don't want the 'else'. remove everything after the bracket preceding else.